# Prefill a line with jline

Tags: java, readline, jline

Using either JLine (or JLine2), is it possible to issue a call to `readline` on a `ConsoleReader` and have, in addition to the standard prompt, the buffer be pre-filled with a string of my choosing?

I have tried to do, e.g.:

```
reader.getCursorBuffer().write("Default");
reader.readLine("Prompt> ");
```

This seems to indeed write into the buffer, but the line only displays the prompt. If I press enter, `readLine` returns `"Default"` as I would expect. If I clear the screen, the buffer is redrawn and shown correctly.

My understanding is that I should somehow call `reader.redrawLine()` right after the call to `readLine`. This last one however is blocking, which makes it hard (not impossible, but it certainly feels wrong to use a second thread for that).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into exactly this use case today.

It's a bit of a hack, but I was able to preload text into the JLine buffer and then let the user edit it by doing this:

```
String preloadReadLine(ConsoleReader reader, String prompt, String preload)
    throws IOException
{
    reader.resetPromptLine(prompt, preload, 0);
    reader.print("\r");
    return reader.readLine(prompt);
}
```

Yeah, the printing of `\r` is a hack, but it seems to make the thing work.

I'm using JLine-2.13.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do that using a thread (yes, it does feel wrong, but I found no other way).

I took inspiration from code found [in JLine itself](https://github.com/jline/jline2/blob/master/src/main/java/jline/console/ConsoleReader.java#L3798) that also uses a thread for similar purposes.

In Scala:

```scala
      val thr = new Thread() {
        override def run() = {
          reader.putString("Default")
          reader.flush()
          // Another way is:
          // reader.getCursorBuffer.write("Default") // writes into the buffer without displaying
          // out.print("D*f*ult") // here you can choose to display something different
          // reader.flush()
        }
      }
      thr.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
      thr.setDaemon(true)
      thr.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Update for JLine3:

This can be accomplished with one of the existing overloads of `readLine`:

```
readLine(String prompt, Character mask, String buffer)
```

For example, `reader.readLine("> ", null, "abc")` will yield `> abc` where `abc` is part of the buffer being edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want either `resetPromptLine` or `putStream` if you already have the prompt set.

Not to hijack your question but I can't figure out how to simply print a line replacing the prompt (ostensibly or visually pushing the prompt down with a message above it).